# Excel, list of distinct values with a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use this formula to get a list of distinct values from column A to column C.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$100,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$100),0,0),0))
```

How can I have a list of distinct values from column A that have a certain text ("a") on column B? Something like:

```
A   B   C
1 - a - 1
1 - a - 3
2 - b - 4
3 - a -
4 - a -
5 - b -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty way would be to put in a "helper" column, for example, in D1:

```
=IF(B1="a",A1,"")
```

Then just replace A with D in your formula.

Answer (score 1):

Do a pivot table summarizing by Column B first then by Column A (you can do this one down the side and the other across the top) Look in the section where Column B has a value of “A” And you should see counts for the different values of Column A. If you want you can click on the label for Column B that and you get a list of check boxes where you can select on the Value “A” for Column B

Comment: Thanks, although I know that works, I can't use it. This is part of a larger macro that makes reports in a specific format, ready to print. The parameters change and it can't depend on users using pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [SpeedTools](http://www.decisionmodels.com/FastExcelV3SpeedTools.htm) LISTDISTINCTS and FILTER.IFS functions

`{=LISTDISTINCTS(FILTER.IFS(0,$A$2:$B$100,1,2,"a"),,,,,1)}`

You need to select cells in column C, type the formula (without the {}) in the formula bar and then press Control-Shift-Enter to enter it as a multi-cell array formula.
 
Disclaimer: I develop and sell the SpeedTools product