# Find a specific value in 2nd Column and distinct all its 1st column using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to try if its possible to First match the value in a cell into the data from the **Column B**. Then if there are matches, execute Distinct formula to get all the distinct record from **Column A**

I am new to excel though he-he-he. Because I always use the MS Access coz its easy. but excel so complicated :(.
Please help this new guy.

Comment: Try MATCH and INDEX.

Comment: Kindly elaborate the formula please, May I have some sample?

Comment: Try searching for 'list of distinct values with a condition - here's one example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921262/excel-list-of-distinct-values-with-a-condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we want to find all instances of **Michael** in column **B** and retrieve the distinct items from column **A**.

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(B1="Michael",A1,"")
```

and in **C2** enter:

```
=IF(AND(B2="Michael",COUNTIF($C$1:C1,A2)=0),A2,"")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

If required, it is very easy to remove the empties from column **C** to produce a compact list.